# How to get Google Talk ID from email id of user?

Tags: google-api, google-talk, google-hangouts

I need to get the Google Talk ID `xxxxx@public.talk.google.com` . Can I get this using the email(gmail) id of the user?

If not, is there any way to get this using oauth?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: @Alex nope. I have kind of given up. Post an answer if you succeed.

Comment: Researching it now, and I saw that Pidgin somehow manages to do that, so I asked them on their IRC channel. The response is that it happens on the Google server and my understanding is that this happens automatically - so I'm examining Pidgin's code now, that's as close as I got.